# How to Extend SwarmActivity? (getting "Cannot resolve symbol 'SwarmActivity'"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I followed the instructions in http://swarmconnect.com/admin/docs/setup to setup Swarm in my Android app in Android Studio.

Here is what I did so far:

Step 1)
I have imported the SwarmConnect library by downloading the library and importing it as a module (by choosing the library after clicking Import Module)

Step 2)
I added
    `manifestmerger.enabled=true`
to both gradle.properties and local.properties files.

Step 3)
I extended SwarmActivity instead of Activity in my app
    `public class MyActivity extends SwarmActivity {`
but I got the error: "Cannot resolve symbol 'SwarmActivity'".

I also tried the alternative solution in Step 3 by adding in my onCreate(); onResume(); onPause() methods
    `Swarm.setActive(this);`
but I got the error: "Cannot resolve symbol 'Swarm'"

Comment: may be you are not properly adding the jar file or the library project in your project

Comment: I also tried to include import com.swarmconnect.Swarm;  and it is detecting the com.swarmconnect but can't resolve Swarm.